# categorising lists by names and counting

Tags: python, list, slice, dictionary

i hav a list of lines like so

```
animals = ['i am a dog', 'i am a cat','i am a dog','i am a bird','i am a dog']
```

I need to categorise the list so that it categorises them by what animal they are.  I then need to count them and if they are over 2 animal for each category print a message etc.

Would i categorise the list by using slicing for 7+ characters or another method? and if someone could give me an example it would be great

Answer (score 1):

you can use collectios.Counter.

you can use the following:

```
from collections import Counter

animals = [var[7:] for var in animals]
cnt = Counter(animals)

for ani in animals:
    if cnt[ani] > 2:
        print ani
```